# PHP - Set generated image as background

Tags: php, image

I've wrote a script, that returns a image by hash.
So the URL to the image could look like that: `/i/235345345234234`

When you open this URL by the browser, you can see the image. Now i want to use this URL on another site but as CSS background.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think inline css can play much better part rather than others. Like

```
<div style="background-repeat:no-repeat; height:100px; width:100px; background-image:url('http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png');">test</div>
```

Its just an example css can be modify according to requirement.